# Is it correct to say "are you getting used to your new friends now?" or "do you know them better now"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Your son feels shy and don't want to play with the children the he meets for the first time, but after a while he starting to play with them more.

Can we use "**get used to + someone**"?

For example,

Is it correct to say "**are you getting used to your new friends now?**" or "**do you know them better now**"?

Comment: I'd say that *usually*, if you ***get used to X***, the implication is that your initial interaction with X was unpleasant, but over time you've become [***inured***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inure#:~:text=transitive%20verb,to%20the%20benefit%20of%20employees) (you've come to ***accept*** something ***undesirable***). And in most cases where that implication ***doesn't*** apply, as in *I've got used to drinking expensive wine*, the implication is that familiarity has bred contempt (or at least, you ***no longer value*** the thing so much as you used to).  No good for friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two examples of:

> are you getting used to your new friends now?

And:

> do you know them better now?

Are all proper grammar.

The first sentence uses "getting used to", which means:

> If you get used to something or someone, you become familiar with it or get to know them, so that you no longer feel that the thing or person is unusual or surprising. 
> [<sub>reference</sub>](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-used-to)

Which completely matches your case.

The second sentence just says "do you know them better now", one of "know"s meanings is:

> to be familiar with or have experience and understanding of
> [<sub>reference</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know)

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers that 'get used to' _doesn't_ 'completely match the case'. You get used to new surroundings or a different routine, but to use it of people suggests that you found something odd or disagreeable about them at first. Much better to say "Are you getting to know them better?"